# List ALL Ansible variables for a host or group with an ad hoc command?

Tags: ansible

Ansible variables come from a variety of sources. It is for example possible to provide host_vars and group_vars by creating YAML files in a subfolder named `host_vars` and `group_vars` respectively of the folder containing the inventory file.

How can I list **all of the variables** Ansible *would* know about a group or host inside a playbook? Note: I tried `ansible -m debug -e 'var=hostvars' host` and `ansible -m debug -e '- debug: var=hostvars'` to no avail.

Hint: `ansible <group|host> -m setup` is *not* the correct answer as it does *not* include all the variables that come from other sources (it only contains `{ "ansible_facts" : { ... } }`. In fact it does not even include variables provided by a dynamic inventory script (via `_meta` and so on).

Ansible version: 1.9.1.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`ansible <host pattern> -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]"`  seems to work.
Replace `<host pattern>` by any valid [host pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html).

Valid variable sources (`host_vars`, `group_vars`, `_meta` in a dynamic inventory, etc.) are all taken into account.

With dynamic inventory script `hosts.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if test "$1" = "--host"; then
        echo {}
else
        cat <<EOF
{
  "ungrouped": [ "x.example.com", "y.example.com" ],
  "group1": [ "a.example.com" ],
  "group2": [ "b.example.com" ],
  "groups": {
    "children": [ "group1", "group2" ],
    "vars": { "ansible_ssh_user": "user" }
  },
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "a.example.com": { "ansible_ssh_host": "10.0.0.1" },
      "b.example.com": { "ansible_ssh_host": "10.0.0.2" }
    }
  }
}
EOF
fi
```

You can get:

```
$ chmod +x hosts.sh
$ ansible -i hosts.sh a.example.com -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]"
a.example.com | success >> {
    "var": {
        "hostvars": {
            "ansible_ssh_host": "10.0.0.1", 
            "ansible_ssh_user": "user", 
            "group_names": [
                "group1", 
                "groups"
            ], 
            "groups": {
                "all": [
                    "x.example.com", 
                    "y.example.com", 
                    "a.example.com", 
                    "b.example.com"
                ], 
                "group1": [
                    "a.example.com"
                ], 
                "group2": [
                    "b.example.com"
                ], 
                "groups": [
                    "a.example.com", 
                    "b.example.com"
                ], 
                "ungrouped": [
                    "x.example.com", 
                    "y.example.com"
                ]
            }, 
            "inventory_hostname": "a.example.com", 
            "inventory_hostname_short": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With ansible `2.0.2`, this doesn't seem to work anymore. The output is `localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "hostvars": "<ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVars object at 0x7f320943da10>"
}`

Comment: Suggested edit to use ``"var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]"`` on ansible > 2.0

Comment: For 1.9.4 it doesn't return the stuff returned by `ansible my.hostname.example.com -m setup -i ../my/inventory/hosts.example -u root`

Comment: This worked for me `ansible host-name -m debug -a "var=[var_name]" -i inventory/testing/hosts`

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Adding a small tip to the really good answer above, if you want to programmatically poke around you can

Use the existing answer for **hostvars**:

```
ansible -m debug myhost -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_version"
```

But  **ansible_facts** is empty because `debug` doesn't run the `setup` module. So you need to try something extra like `jq` after trimming the output to make it valid json.

```
ansible -m setup myhost | sed 's#.*SUCCESS =>##' | jq .ansible_facts.ansible_all_ipv4_addresses
```

I thought people might find this useful when investigating the giant wall of text that comes back in ansible facts when you just want one thing like `jq .ansible_facts.ansible_devices.vda.size`

Answer (score 2):

FYI: [This](https://github.com/f500/ansible-dumpall) github project shows you how to list 90% of variables across all hosts. I find it more globally useful than single host commands.  The README includes instructions for building a simple inventory report.  It's even more valuable to run this at the end of a playbook to see all the Facts. To also debug Task behaviour use register: